# Xcode 10 segmentation fault

Tags: swift, xcode10

I stumbled upon segmentation fault 11 issue while compiling project on Xcode 10(+ change to swift 4.2), previously was Xcode 9.4.

I attached log, and class if it should help.

### Compile log

Xcode gave me no clue with compile log - only saying it happened in OptionDto:

```
    While verifying SIL function "@$s6Wander9OptionDtoVAA0B0Vs5Error_pIegnrzo_AcEsAF_pIeggozo_TR".
 for <<debugloc at "<compiler-generated>":0:0>>0  swift                    0x000000011159e328 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 40
1  swift                    0x000000011159d5a5 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 85
2  swift                    0x000000011159e932 SignalHandler(int) + 258
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff7793bf5a _sigtramp + 26
4  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x000000011b01c608 _sigtramp + 2741896904
5  libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007fff776d91ae abort + 127
6  swift                    0x000000010e8582b9 (anonymous namespace)::SILVerifier::_require(bool, llvm::Twine const&, std::__1::function<void ()> const&) + 633
7  swift                    0x000000010e873a4c (anonymous namespace)::SILVerifier::checkFullApplySite(swift::FullApplySite) + 636
8  swift                    0x000000010e85e097 swift::SILInstructionVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::SILVerifier, void>::visit(swift::SILInstruction*) + 11255
9  swift                    0x000000010e85a01c (anonymous namespace)::SILVerifier::visitSILBasicBlock(swift::SILBasicBlock*) + 1196
10 swift                    0x000000010e8545f7 swift::SILFunction::verify(bool) const + 7095
11 swift                    0x000000010e857693 swift::SILModule::verify() const + 211
12 swift                    0x000000010e2b4971 swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::~SILGenModule() + 33
13 swift                    0x000000010e2bfc44 swift::SILModule::constructSIL(swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SILOptions&, swift::FileUnit*) + 1460
14 swift                    0x000000010e2bfd4c swift::performSILGeneration(swift::FileUnit&, swift::SILOptions&) + 44
15 swift                    0x000000010da30df2 performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 7186
16 swift                    0x000000010da2e14d swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 3021
17 swift                    0x000000010d9e018e main + 686
18 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff7762d015 start + 1
error: Abort trap: 6
```

and also when I downloaded snapshot:

```
  SIL verification failed: apply doesn't have right number of arguments for function: site.getNumArguments() == substConv.getNumSILArguments()
Verifying instruction:
   %0 = argument of bb0 : $OptionDto              // user: %2
   %1 = argument of bb0 : $@callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed OptionDto) -> (@out Option, @error Error) // user: %2
->   try_apply %1(%0) : $@callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed OptionDto) -> (@out Option, @error Error), normal bb1, error bb2 // id: %2
In function:
// thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed OptionDto) -> (@out Option, @error @owned Error)
sil shared [transparent] [serializable] [thunk] @$s6Wander9OptionDtoVAA0B0Vs5Error_pIegnrzo_AcEsAF_pIeggozo_TR : $@convention(thin) (@guaranteed OptionDto, @guaranteed @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed OptionDto) -> (@out Option, @error Error)) -> (@owned Option, @error Error) {
// %0                                             // user: %2
// %1                                             // user: %2
bb0(%0 : @guaranteed $OptionDto, %1 : @guaranteed $@callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed OptionDto) -> (@out Option, @error Error)):
  try_apply %1(%0) : $@callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed OptionDto) -> (@out Option, @error Error), normal bb1, error bb2 // id: %2

// %3                                             // user: %4
bb1(%3 : @trivial $()):                           // Preds: bb0
  return %3 : $()                                 // id: %4

// %5                                             // users: %7, %6
bb2(%5 : @owned $Error):                          // Preds: bb0
  %6 = builtin "willThrow"(%5 : $Error) : $()
  throw %5 : $Error                               // id: %7
} // end sil function '$s6Wander9OptionDtoVAA0B0Vs5Error_pIegnrzo_AcEsAF_pIeggozo_TR'
```

### OptionDto

```
import ObjectMapper
struct OptionDto {
    var correctAnswer: Bool?
    var id: Int?
    var optionText: String?
    var task: Int?
}

extension OptionDto: Mappable {
    init?(map: Map) {}

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        correctAnswer <- map["correctAnswer"]
        id <- map["id"]
        optionText <- map["optionText"]
        task <- map["task"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by line, in other file, while converting dto to domain object:

```
try (input.selectTaskOptions ?? []).map(optionConverter.convert)
```

where convert function looks like this:

```
class OptionConverter: Converter<OptionDto, Option> {

    override func convert(input: OptionDto) throws -> Option {
        guard let id = input.id, let isCorrect = input.correctAnswer else { throw ConversionError() }

        return Option(correctAnswer: isCorrect, id: Id(value: id), optionText: input.optionText ?? "")
    }
}
```

Changing it to this, helped:

```
try (input.selectTaskOptions ?? []).map { try optionConverter.convert(input: $0) }
```

Does anyone have a clue, why the previous syntax is not working, am I missing something, which makes it ambiguos in any way for compiler?

Comment: More to that, without using generics, it will also pass. I will update upon the response from bug reporter.